# really struggling to find the next path to develop my javascript knowledge

Tags: javascript

I have completed codeacademy twice, freecodecamp twice and read a few online articles...I believe I now have a good understanding of the fundamentals of Javascript.

However, I feel lost in terms of where to go next. People say build projects, but where do I start? How do I plan? Even though I know the fundamentals of Javascript, I still feel there is a lot to learn. I feel like I will only truly start understanding Javascript once I start putting projects together but I cant think of any.

Also, codeacademy, freecodecamp and these other online course websites dont seem to really teach DOM manipulation. Is there any online coding sites, similar to the ones mentioned, which will allow me to practice DOM manipulation?

I would be hufely grateful if people who have developed their understanding in Javascript can give me some advice based on how they did it.

I am just sitting here staring at my laptop and going back and forth. I cant really seem to figure out what to do next, now that I have gained a basic understanding of the core concepts of Javascript. Please guys, help!

Comment: get a job as a junior web dev.  or, go download Screeps

Comment: Questions like these are offtopic here, try on Quora or JavaScript subreddit...

Comment: build a todo-list app without a tutorial.

Comment: Thank you guys. Sorry about posting in the wrong section. I am new to stackoverflow. I have noted this for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a very good question, but I still would like to try and explain.

**Questions you need to ask yourself**

1. Frontend or backend js?

I assume frontend based on the "DOM manipulation" part, but there is also Node.js for the backend with it's own unique API to use and interact with the operating system.

2. Do I want to use libraries and/or frameworks

Depending on your needs and preferences you will come in touch with these things, they all have their own learning curve, on top of learning js. Libraries are mostly just function in order to help you. However frameworks like Vue and Angular require a way of writing your code that is like it's own language. <sup>(opinionated)</sup>

3. What version(s) of js and browsers do you want to support?

Javascript has evolved over time and the javascript engines in browsers as well. Older IE browsers will be harder to support without the help of a library like jQuery.

**Now about the learning part and where you can practice.**

There are probably thousands of great sites to practice, however I will give you my favorites.

- The stackoverflow documentation on javascript (top navigation on this page)
- I will get hate for this: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/)
- To read the docs on [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript)
- interactive on both [codeschool](https://www.codeschool.com/learn/javascript) and [codeacademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript)
- [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for practicing in a closed environment
- https://bento.io/topic/javascript
- https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/javascript/
- http://www.allitebooks.com/ for specific ebooks

Have a look at what frameworks are popular nowadays and why. If they suit your needs. Learn them one or two at a time but not more, so you won't mix them all up in the end. Try to at least understand OOP in javascript even if you don't intend to use it later. Anyone feel free to expand this answer because it is hard to cover it all myself.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response, Thomas! I am unsure what made this not a good question. I am assuming by the other response that this is the wrong place to post. I am new to stackoverflow. I apologise if I have gone about asking my quesiton the wrong way or if it seems silly. As you can probably make out I am new to the programming field and have a great desire to become a web developer. Anyway, I will not contiue writing on. You have given me plenty of suggestions and I will now start to take all of those on board. Thanks once again!